# readOnlyRootFilesystem prevents my code from writing logs

Tags: kubernetes, filesystems, security-context

I added in my deployment `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true` but running my code ends with the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno30] Read-only file system: '/project/logs/dbt.log'
```

But `/project/logs/dbt.log` is NOT a root path.

Any idea why does it happen?

here's a more elaborated manifest I'm using:

```
spec:
  containers:
    .
    .
    .
    .     
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
      privileged: false
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      runAsNonRoot: true
    .
    .
    .
    .      
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 101
```

Comment: You need to mount a volume to write to a file inside the container.

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand, root path is `/`. My project is writing to `/something/something`. Does `readOnlyRootFilesystem` block ANYTHING under `/`?

Comment: Yes, `readOnlyRootFilesystem` will keep you from writing anywhere other than a mounted volume.  It's not just the root directory but the entire root filesystem.

Comment: If this is really about logs, though, a better solution might be to reconfigure your application to send its logs to stdout.  `kubectl logs` will be able to retrieve them without needing to access the container filesystem, and typical log collectors know how to read the container logs as well.

Comment: Please don't write logs to a certain file, logs should be written to stdout. If you want to write it to a file, mount a volume even. You could also use an ephemeral volume (will get deleted once the pod restarts)

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a temporary volume (**same lifespan** as your pod) to avoid writing to root:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: logs
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:
  .
  .
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
      privileged: false
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      runAsNonRoot: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /project/logs
```